# naive bayes pyspark 1.3 no response

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I am trying to run a Naive Bayesian classifier for my data in PySpark 1.3

Here is my data sample:

Using a text file, I am converting it into a LabeledPoint object

> 67,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,3.....60,66],[0.45,0.441666666667,0.475,0.0,0.717763157895,0.0,0.497300944669,0.476608187135,0.0,0.0,0.45183714002,0.616666666667,0.966666666667,0.0790064102564,-0.364093614847,0.0679487179487,0.256043956044,0.7,0.449583333333,0.231904697754,0.341666666667,0.06....,0.0]

```
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'path to file')

training, test = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed=0)

model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)

predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))

accuracy = (
    1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda (x, v): x == v).count() / test.count()
)
```

PySpark seems to hang forever on calculating variable model. Does anyone else has faced this issue before? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Naive Bayes algorithm in Spark requires that no features (e.g. x values)  are negative. You can see in your LabeledPoints that -0.364093614847 is negative. This should be throwing an error. So, try going back through your raw data and finding a way to convert anything that is negative to a positive value. In the example below, my data is all between -1.0 and 1.0. I just add 1.0 to all values so that the distributions / means/ standard deviations all remain the same.

Your `data` looks like this:

```
[LabeledPoint(1.0,(1,[0,1,2,3],[-0.5,0.5,0.0,0.8]))], 
[LabeledPoint(0.0,(1,[0,1,2,3],[0.1,0.5,0.5,-0.6]))],
[LabeledPoint(1.0,(1,[0,1,2,3],[0.9,0.1,-0.2,0.7]))]
```

The problem is that data structures in Spark are basically immutable. Therefore, you need to go back to when your data was not yet converted into a LabeledPoint object (e.g. when it was still text). Here is some sample code on how to read in a text file (with some missing values), add one to each feature, then convert to LabeledPoint. Note that this is for a csv, but if you change what is in `split` you can alter it for a tsv or other delimiter.

```
sc.textFile("/your/directory/your-file/*") \
     .map(lambda x: [unicode("") if x1=="nan" else x1 for x1 in x.split(',')[1:]])\
     .map(lambda x: x[0] + " " + " ".join([str(i+1)+":"+str(float(x1)+1) for i,x1 in enumerate(x[1:4]) if x1 != ''])) \ 
     .saveAsTextFile("/your/directory/new-directory/no-neg")
```

This assumes the original file you have takes the form:

`Label, X1, X2, X3, X4`

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I was able to see the error message of not accepting negative value inside Spark Scala shell and running this Naive Bayes code. Little strange the Python Spark 1.3 Shell just hangs on this piece of code.